# What is the difference between technical coaching and mentoring?

Tags: tech-industry, people-management, mentoring

I have seen people using both the terms for similar situations. I do not find much difference between the two. Could someone help me understand the difference between technical coaching vs mentoring in software organization with senior and junior folks?

Comment: It's unlikely there is intended to be much of a difference. If I were to guess, a mentor would assist with non-technical things too. But it's more likely we just have two terms for the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mentoring is about giving advice to someone on how to progress their career.  It will likely involve a number of sessions, spaced over a period of months or years.  It's not related to any particular technology.

Technical coaching would be more focussed on specific skills and technologies that the mentor is helping the mentee to learn.

Comment: Even more tersely, technical coaching is Stack Exchange/Programmers.SE; mentoring is Workplace.SE.